# Qt4 w/ PySide: How to Create Animation Loop for a Widget?

Tags: python, qt, animation, qt4, pyside

I am using a `QWidget` to render x and y-repeated shapes in different color progressions and like to transform these colors over time. In this widget I rely on `QPainter`'s drawing api solely to draw and create the shapes.

What is the best way to put a particular widget into an animation loop with Qt4, so that `paintEvent()` is fired periodically, preferably at a configurable frame rate / time interval? (much like what tools like processing do with their stage)

Additionally, would you recommend using another widget type for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users over at reddit got me on the right track:
http://redd.it/24kogy

As suggested there [`QTimer`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QTimer.html) works fine. In the class of your widget you could apply it like this:

```
timer = QTimer(self)
timer.setInterval(20) # interval in ms
self.connect(timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.update)
timer.start()
```

Relevant imports are

```
from PySide.QtCore import QTimer, SIGNAL
```